# Motherboard or PSU causing reboot loop?

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, infinite-loop

Error description: PC will reboot and fans will power up but will immediately restart before getting to BIOS. No display on screen. No beep sounds from speakers.

I've been doing research for now and have tested the following components and removed them:

-2x4gb ram (tried swap method too)

-GPU

-2 HDD

-1 SSD

I have also breadboarded to ensure that the normal power button has not shorted

**The remaining components are:**

-Intel i5 CPU

- MSI z77a g45 motherboard (cleared CMOS as well)

-seasonic 100-240 VAC

I have reseated the CPU as well although have not applied new heat paste.

Anyone know what is causing this?

Maybe I should also note that I've had weird rebooting problems before, but never a loop. On some cold mornings, I would power up the PC and it would crash just before the windows logo, but then be fine afterwards.

Comment: If you remove RAM, does it still reboot? If not then keep RAM in there. If you remove hard drives does it reboot? If so, remove hard drives. It's strange that your question doesn't specify that you're testing with RAM and no hard drives.   Really if you suspect a PSU issue, you should change PSU.  I don't know how you'd do that if you're not a hoarding computer techie, maybe you have another computer in the house.

Comment: Sounds like a degrading component but hard to tell which. Could be any of the remaining components you've specified.

Comment: Turns out it was indeed the motherboard. system is running now! :3